# How can I get transmit and receive times with ping command

Tags: ping

How do I ping a computer/server and get the transmit and receive times separately instead of getting one round trip time. I'm using hrping and I can get transmit and receive times from computers on my local network.

```
D:\Portable\hrping>hrping 192.168.1.1 -M
This is hrPING v5.07.1148 by cFos Software GmbH -- http://www.cfos.de

Source address is 192.168.1.17; using ICMP timestamp, ID=801c
Pinging 192.168.1.1 [192.168.1.1]
with 0 bytes data (40 bytes IP):

From 192.168.1.1: bytes=40 seq=0001 TTL=64 ID=62f3 time=0.626ms tx=1ms rx=0ms
From 192.168.1.1: bytes=40 seq=0002 TTL=64 ID=62f4 time=0.923ms tx=1ms rx=0ms
From 192.168.1.1: bytes=40 seq=0003 TTL=64 ID=62f5 time=0.336ms tx=1ms rx=-1ms
From 192.168.1.1: bytes=40 seq=0004 TTL=64 ID=62f6 time=0.320ms tx=1ms rx=-1ms

Packets: sent=4, rcvd=4, error=0, lost=0 (0.0% loss) in 1.502086 sec
RTTs in ms: min/avg/max/dev: 0.320 / 0.551 / 0.923 / 0.246
Bandwidth in kbytes/sec: sent=0.106, rcvd=0.106
```

but it doesn't work for anything on the internet.

```
D:\Portable\hrping>hrping google.com -M
This is hrPING v5.07.1148 by cFos Software GmbH -- http://www.cfos.de

Source address is 192.168.1.17; using ICMP timestamp, ID=082b
Pinging google.com [172.217.16.238]
with 0 bytes data (40 bytes IP):

Timeout waiting for seq=0001
Timeout waiting for seq=0002
Timeout waiting for seq=0003
Timeout waiting for seq=0004

Packets: sent=4, rcvd=0, error=0, lost=4 (100.0% loss) in 1.503945 sec
RTTs in ms: min/avg/max/dev: 0.000 / 0.000 / 0.000 / 0.000
Bandwidth in kbytes/sec: sent=0.106, rcvd=0.000
```

I got this message from hrping and I setup a firewall rule. And still nothing.

```
hrPing did not get any replies.  This might be due to a firewall setting.

If you use Windows firewall with default settings, you need to add a rule to
allow hrPing full incoming ICMP traffic:

Go to Control Panel, Windows Firewall and click on Advanced settings on the
left.  A new dialog appears: on its left pane right-click 'Inbound Rules' and
select 'New rule...'  In the following wizard select 'Custom', click Next,
select 'All programs', click Next, select 'ICMPv4' as 'Protocol type', click
Next 4 times and enter 'hrPing' as 'Name' and click 'Finish'.

Don't forget to disable or delete this rule when you no longer need it!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hrping -M` uses ICMP *Timestamp Request* packets instead of the usual Echo Request.

Many administrators configure their servers to only allow a very limited list of ICMP request types – they often allow ICMP Echo (which is what everyone associates with 'ping') and nothing else.

So while hrPing's message is correct that this may be a firewall issue, the problem is with the firewall on the *other* end, and you really cannot do anything about that – other than try to ping something else instead.

(For example, "superuser.com" does answer to Timestamp Request, while "google.com" simply does not. The "cfos.de" website, where I downloaded hrPing from, also answers Timestamp Requests but in a slightly weird way.)

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you are pinging networks that have disabled ICMP ping.  Many networks disable ping for security, such as to prevent ping flooding.  Google is one such company.

Try pinging amazon.com and yahoo.com as they currently allow pings.

Comment: didn't work for amazon.com and yahoo.com but worked for bbc.co.uk

Comment: 1 of 3 My home internet ping is very good, low and stable 7ms to google.com 15ms to servers in west and north europe, but for some reason I was having issues with latency in games. It was unpredictable. lag compensation (where server goes back in time to get location data for players, bullets etc to see if they collide) for almost all games wouldn't register half of my shots but for other players it would count shots which would clearly miss as hit. I figured there was a difference or unstability in my up or down latencies.

Comment: 2 of 3 I used clumsy in past to increase my up ping and drop and delay sending packets. And that turned thing other way round. Shots which would clearly miss would were now registering as a hit for me but for other player shots which were clear hit would miss. But looking at transmit (tx) and receive (rx) times they seem similar and stable.
From 151.101.0.81: bytes=40 seq=0001 TTL=58 ID=45e4 time=7.625ms tx=4ms rx=3ms

From 151.101.0.81: bytes=40 seq=0002 TTL=58 ID=4612 time=7.872ms tx=4ms rx=4ms

From 151.101.0.81: bytes=40 seq=0003 TTL=58 ID=4634 time=7.873ms tx=4ms rx=4ms

Comment: 3 of 3 From 151.101.0.81: bytes=40 seq=0004 TTL=58 ID=4678 time=7.602ms tx=4ms rx=3ms
From 151.101.0.81: bytes=40 seq=0005 TTL=58 ID=46cc time=7.884ms tx=4ms rx=4ms
From 151.101.0.81: bytes=40 seq=0006 TTL=58 ID=46cd time=7.893ms tx=4ms rx=4ms
From 151.101.0.81: bytes=40 seq=0007 TTL=58 ID=4720 time=7.930ms tx=4ms rx=4ms
From 151.101.0.81: bytes=40 seq=0008 TTL=58 ID=4794 time=7.390ms tx=4ms rx=3ms
From 151.101.0.81: bytes=40 seq=0009 TTL=58 ID=479e time=7.953ms tx=4ms rx=4ms

Comment: So, what's the issue? how is my mobile internet (4G LTE) with it's much higher and unstable ping is much better for gaming than my wired FTTC home internet?